# Cannot read property "authenticate" of undefined - Parse Server with Account Kit

Tags: javascript, parse-server, account-kit

#### Issue Description

I am using Parse Server 3.0.0 and trying to get it to work with Facebook's Account Kit. I have followed the instructions in the docs and done the following:

1. Configured  **facebookaccountkit** inside **auth** passed to **ParseServer()**

---

```
var polaris = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/polaris',
  cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: 'polarisAppId',
  masterKey: 'polarisMasterKey',
  serverURL: 'http://' + ipAddress + ':1337/polaris',
  auth: {
    facebookaccountkit: {
      appIds: ["app_id_here"],
      appSecret: "app_secret_here"
    },
  }
});
```

2. Getting Access Token inside my Android by going through phone verification.
3. Calling **_linkWith()** in cloud code as:

---

```
let accountKitAuthData = {
    "id": accountKitId,
    "access_token": accessToken,
    "last_refresh": lastRefresh
}

let user = new Parse.User()
user._linkWith('facebookaccountkit', accountKitAuthData).then(function (user) {
    console.log("linkWith method finished ")
    console.log("user object type " + (typeof user))
});
```

However, after all this, I am getting the following error:

```
(node:21807) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined`
```

My best guess is that the **facebookaccountkit** provider is not getting registered due to some reason but I may be wrong. Please help!

#### Expected Results

Linking of user with facebookaccountkit credentials

#### Actual Outcome

Error:

```
(node:21807) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined`
```

#### Environment Setup

- **Server**

  - parse-server version : 3.0.0
  - Operating System:     Ubuntu
  - Hardware:             -
  - Localhost or remote server? (AWS, Heroku, Azure, Digital Ocean, etc): Google Cloud Platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
let accountKitAuthData = {
    "id": accountKitId,
    "access_token": accessToken,
    "last_refresh": lastRefresh
}

let user = new Parse.User()
user._linkWith('facebookaccountkit', { authData: accountKitAuthData }).then(function (user) {
    console.log("linkWith method finished ")
    console.log("user object type " + (typeof user))
});
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!